# mysql calculate multiplication with group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, multiplication

Please how to calculate multiplication with group by.

For example

table

```
id      value
1       1
1       2
2       1
2       2
2       3
3       0
3       3
```

I want next result using group by.

```
id      value
1       2
2       6
3       0
```

Thanks too much in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify: You are searching for a `sum()` equivalent in order to multiply, right?

Comment: see [this post](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17267/how-do-i-create-a-user-defined-aggregate-function) particularly the post using exp on the sum of logs..

Comment: Note post from @amdixon gives a good solution, but will fail if there are values >= 0. coalesce(exp(sum(log(coalesce(*the field you want to multiply*,1))),0) will resolve the problem if you know values will be >= 0, otherwise -ve will also cause 0 to be returned

Comment: @PaulF good point about log(negative_values), perhaps you could handle this with a case statement

Comment: @amdixon : you would need to use abs(field) & count the number of negative values, if odd then value is -ve otherwise +ve. Not sure how easy it would be

Comment: @PaulF yeah would be a bit awkward..

Comment: Thanks guys!
I can solve a probrem by your favor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
exp(sum(log(coalesce(*the field you want to multiply*,1))))

SELECT
    id,
    round( exp( sum( log( COALESCE ( `value`, 0 ) ) ) ) ) AS `value` 
FROM
    tests 
GROUP BY
    id;

Sorry but that will not work correctly if 0 value is present in column

Comment: You need to prove something by writing code, not only give the link